# One more incorrect result of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

Let us dsolve that Cauchy problem in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
sol = DSolve[{Sqrt[y[x]] + (1 + x)*y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, x]
```

> `{{y -> Function[{x}, 1/4 (4 - 4 Log[1 + x] + Log[1 + x]^2)]}, {y ->  Function[{x}, 1/4 (4 + 4 Log[1 + x] + Log[1 + x]^2)]}}`

Two solutions contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem (see "Local existence and uniqueness theorem simplified" in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)).

Only the first one is a true solution as

```
FullSimplify[{Sqrt[y[x]] + (1 + x)*y'[x], y[0]} /. sol[[1]], Assumptions -> x >= 0]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{-2 + Log[1 + x], Log[1 + x] >= 2}}, 0], 1}`

and

```
FullSimplify[{Sqrt[y[x]] + (1 + x)*y'[x], y[0]} /. sol[[2]], Assumptions -> x >= 0]
```

> `{2 + Log[1 + x], 1}`

show.

Does there exist a symbolic workaround (The result of `nsol = NDSolve[{Sqrt[y[x]] + (1 + x)*y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 1},  y, {x, -1, 2}]` seems correct.)?

Comment: Not sure what "one more" means, but related are
[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119515)
and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249656)
and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270890).

Comment: @user293787: "One more" stands to avoid the duplication of the title with [that question of me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249656/incorrect-result-of-dsolve). Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: If it so simple to verify the solution, why Math. does not do it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround is the substitution `y[x]->z[x]^2` with assumption `z[x]>0`:

```
odez = ode /. y -> (z[#]^2 &) // Simplify[#, z[x] > 0] &
solz = DSolve[{odez, z[0] == 1}, z[x], x][[1]] /. z[x] -> Sqrt[y[x]]
(*{Sqrt[y[x]] -> 1/2 (2 - Log[1 + x])}*)
```

Comment: Thank you. All that is made rather by hand, especially `Simplify[#, z[x] > 0]`. Without `Simplify` two solutions are produced `{{z[x] -> 1/2 (2 - Log[1 + x])}, {z[x] -> 1/2 (2 + Log[1 + x])}}`.

Comment: You asked for a workaround...

Comment: Indeed. I will be waiting some time before drawing  a decision.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a condition on y'[0] seems a workaround, maybe:

```
ode = Sqrt[y[x]] + (1 + x)*y'[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{ode, Reduce[{ode, y[0] == 1} /. x -> 0]}, y, x]
```

> ```
> {{y -> Function[{x}, 1/4 (4 - 4 Log[1 + x] + Log[1 + x]^2)]}}
> ```

```
Simplify[{ode, y[0] == 1} /. sol, -1/100 < x < 1/100]
```

> ```
> {{True, True}}
> ```

Comment: +1. Nice and sure unexpected and tricky.